# Google maps, plot a route with multiple markers, hide markers except for last marker

Tags: google-maps, path, google-maps-markers

I have a google maps and am using the below fiddle as a template.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aau12ypm/8/)

This map shows 38 markers, each marker has the standard balloon icon so it becomes hard to view the actual plotted path for all the balloons.

I want only the last marker to have an icon, the rest should just show the path but route according to the markers.

Somthing like

```
 var stations = [
        {lat: 48.9812840, lng: 21.2171920, name: 'Station 1', marker:none},
        {lat: 48.9832841, lng: 21.2176398, name: 'Station 2', marker:none},
        {lat: 48.9856443, lng: 21.2209088, name: 'Station 3', marker:none},
        {lat: 48.9861461, lng: 21.2261563, name: 'Station 4', marker:none},
        {lat: 48.9874682, lng: 21.2294855, name: 'Station 5', marker:none},
        {lat: 48.9909244, lng: 21.2295512, name: 'Station 6', marker:balloon},
```

etc etc

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map {
    height: 100%;     
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="for (var r of gRenderers) r.setMap(gMap);">Show line</button>

<button onclick="for (var r of gRenderers) r.setMap(null);">Hide line</button>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
    window.gMap = map;

    // list of points
    var stations = [
        {lat: 48.9812840, lng: 21.2171920, name: 'Station 1'},
        {lat: 48.9832841, lng: 21.2176398, name: 'Station 2'},
        {lat: 48.9856443, lng: 21.2209088, name: 'Station 3'},
        {lat: 48.9861461, lng: 21.2261563, name: 'Station 4'},
        {lat: 48.9874682, lng: 21.2294855, name: 'Station 5'},
        {lat: 48.9909244, lng: 21.2295512, name: 'Station 6'},
        {lat: 48.9928871, lng: 21.2292352, name: 'Station 7'},
        {lat: 48.9921334, lng: 21.2246742, name: 'Station 8'},
        {lat: 48.9943196, lng: 21.2234792, name: 'Station 9'},
        {lat: 48.9966345, lng: 21.2221262, name: 'Station 10'},
        {lat: 48.9981191, lng: 21.2271386, name: 'Station 11'},
        {lat: 49.0009168, lng: 21.2359527, name: 'Station 12'},
        {lat: 49.0017950, lng: 21.2392890, name: 'Station 13'},
        {lat: 48.9991912, lng: 21.2398272, name: 'Station 14'},
        {lat: 48.9959850, lng: 21.2418410, name: 'Station 15'},
        {lat: 48.9931772, lng: 21.2453901, name: 'Station 16'},
        {lat: 48.9963512, lng: 21.2525850, name: 'Station 17'},
        {lat: 48.9985134, lng: 21.2508423, name: 'Station 18'},
        {lat: 49.0085000, lng: 21.2508000, name: 'Station 19'},
        {lat: 49.0093000, lng: 21.2528000, name: 'Station 20'},
        {lat: 49.0103000, lng: 21.2560000, name: 'Station 21'},
        {lat: 49.0112000, lng: 21.2590000, name: 'Station 22'},
        {lat: 49.0124000, lng: 21.2620000, name: 'Station 23'},
        {lat: 49.0135000, lng: 21.2650000, name: 'Station 24'},
        {lat: 49.0149000, lng: 21.2680000, name: 'Station 25'},
        {lat: 49.0171000, lng: 21.2710000, name: 'Station 26'},
        {lat: 49.0198000, lng: 21.2740000, name: 'Station 27'},
        {lat: 49.0305000, lng: 21.3000000, name: 'Station 28'},
        // ... as many other stations as you need
    ];

    // Zoom and center map automatically by stations (each station will be in visible map area)
    var lngs = stations.map(function(station) { return station.lng; });
    var lats = stations.map(function(station) { return station.lat; });
    map.fitBounds({
        west: Math.min.apply(null, lngs),
        east: Math.max.apply(null, lngs),
        north: Math.min.apply(null, lats),
        south: Math.max.apply(null, lats),
    });

    // Show stations on the map as markers
    for (var i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: stations[i],
            map: map,
            title: stations[i].name
        });
    }

    // Divide route to several parts because max stations limit is 25 (23 waypoints + 1 origin + 1 destination)
    for (var i = 0, parts = [], max = 8 - 1; i < stations.length; i = i + max)
        parts.push(stations.slice(i, i + max + 1));

    // Service callback to process service results
    var service_callback = function(response, status) {
        if (status != 'OK') {
            console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            return;
        }
        var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        if (!window.gRenderers)
                window.gRenderers = [];
        window.gRenderers.push(renderer);
        renderer.setMap(map);
        renderer.setOptions({ suppressMarkers: true, preserveViewport: true });
        renderer.setDirections(response);
    };

    // Send requests to service to get route (for stations count <= 25 only one request will be sent)
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        // Waypoints does not include first station (origin) and last station (destination)
        var waypoints = [];
        for (var j = 1; j < parts[i].length - 1; j++)
            waypoints.push({location: parts[i][j], stopover: false});
        // Service options
        var service_options = {
            origin: parts[i][0],
            destination: parts[i][parts[i].length - 1],
            waypoints: waypoints,
            travelMode: 'WALKING'
        };
        // Send request
        service.route(service_options, service_callback);
    }
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

Comment: 8.8K rep and you don't know [ask]? Btw. have you tried anything? Have you looked for similar questions? What were you unable to achieve? Why did it not work?

Comment: Criticism warranted, apologies for the lazy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the last marker displayed, only add the last marker to the map.

```
    // Show stations on the map as markers
    for (var i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: stations[i],
            map: i==(stations.length-1) ? map : null,
            title: stations[i].name
        });
    }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/291wmt7g/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="for (var r of gRenderers) r.setMap(gMap);">Show line</button>

<button onclick="for (var r of gRenderers) r.setMap(null);">Hide line</button>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
    window.gMap = map;

    // list of points
    var stations = [
        {lat: 48.9812840, lng: 21.2171920, name: 'Station 1'},
        {lat: 48.9832841, lng: 21.2176398, name: 'Station 2'},
        {lat: 48.9856443, lng: 21.2209088, name: 'Station 3'},
        {lat: 48.9861461, lng: 21.2261563, name: 'Station 4'},
        {lat: 48.9874682, lng: 21.2294855, name: 'Station 5'},
        {lat: 48.9909244, lng: 21.2295512, name: 'Station 6'},
        {lat: 48.9928871, lng: 21.2292352, name: 'Station 7'},
        {lat: 48.9921334, lng: 21.2246742, name: 'Station 8'},
        {lat: 48.9943196, lng: 21.2234792, name: 'Station 9'},
        {lat: 48.9966345, lng: 21.2221262, name: 'Station 10'},
        {lat: 48.9981191, lng: 21.2271386, name: 'Station 11'},
        {lat: 49.0009168, lng: 21.2359527, name: 'Station 12'},
        {lat: 49.0017950, lng: 21.2392890, name: 'Station 13'},
        {lat: 48.9991912, lng: 21.2398272, name: 'Station 14'},
        {lat: 48.9959850, lng: 21.2418410, name: 'Station 15'},
        {lat: 48.9931772, lng: 21.2453901, name: 'Station 16'},
        {lat: 48.9963512, lng: 21.2525850, name: 'Station 17'},
        {lat: 48.9985134, lng: 21.2508423, name: 'Station 18'},
        {lat: 49.0085000, lng: 21.2508000, name: 'Station 19'},
        {lat: 49.0093000, lng: 21.2528000, name: 'Station 20'},
        {lat: 49.0103000, lng: 21.2560000, name: 'Station 21'},
        {lat: 49.0112000, lng: 21.2590000, name: 'Station 22'},
        {lat: 49.0124000, lng: 21.2620000, name: 'Station 23'},
        {lat: 49.0135000, lng: 21.2650000, name: 'Station 24'},
        {lat: 49.0149000, lng: 21.2680000, name: 'Station 25'},
        {lat: 49.0171000, lng: 21.2710000, name: 'Station 26'},
        {lat: 49.0198000, lng: 21.2740000, name: 'Station 27'},
        {lat: 49.0305000, lng: 21.3000000, name: 'Station 28'},
        // ... as many other stations as you need
    ];


    // Zoom and center map automatically by stations (each station will be in visible map area)
    var lngs = stations.map(function(station) {
      return station.lng;
    });
    var lats = stations.map(function(station) {
      return station.lat;
    });
    map.fitBounds({
      west: Math.min.apply(null, lngs),
      east: Math.max.apply(null, lngs),
      north: Math.min.apply(null, lats),
      south: Math.max.apply(null, lats),
    });

    // Show stations on the map as markers
    for (var i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: stations[i],
        map: i == (stations.length - 1) ? map : null,
        title: stations[i].name
      });
    }

    // Divide route to several parts because max stations limit is 25 (23 waypoints + 1 origin + 1 destination)
    for (var i = 0, parts = [], max = 8 - 1; i < stations.length; i = i + max)
      parts.push(stations.slice(i, i + max + 1));

    // Service callback to process service results
    var service_callback = function(response, status) {
      if (status != 'OK') {
        console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        return;
      }
      var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
      if (!window.gRenderers)
        window.gRenderers = [];
      window.gRenderers.push(renderer);
      renderer.setMap(map);
      renderer.setOptions({
        suppressMarkers: true,
        preserveViewport: true
      });
      renderer.setDirections(response);
    };

    // Send requests to service to get route (for stations count <= 25 only one request will be sent)
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      // Waypoints does not include first station (origin) and last station (destination)
      var waypoints = [];
      for (var j = 1; j < parts[i].length - 1; j++)
        waypoints.push({
          location: parts[i][j],
          stopover: false
        });
      // Service options
      var service_options = {
        origin: parts[i][0],
        destination: parts[i][parts[i].length - 1],
        waypoints: waypoints,
        travelMode: 'WALKING'
      };
      // Send request
      service.route(service_options, service_callback);
    }
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```